# Sending file in source element for file in Azure Storage

Tags: image, azure-storage, html-email

I have an email template which uses

```
<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt"><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt"><IMG border=0 hspace=0 alt="" src="file://some image file path"></SPAN></P>
```

, however, now using a cloud based solution with the file to be stored in Blob storage.

If try to copy the path just get the following:

```
<Error>
   <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
   <Message>
      The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:78b69839-201e-00ac-7c8f-e81311000000 Time:2019-04-01T13:35:28.8100122Z
   </Message>
</Error>
```

Could download from storage using C# for an attachment, but don't know how can send the file by specifying in img element within the HTML template.

Comment: What is the access level associated with the container the blob presides in and how are you trying to access the blob? If it is private and you are not passing valid credentials (whether SAS, key, RBAC, or connection string) then it will throw a 404. Reason for throwing a 404 or *Blob Not Exist* is so people can't just snoop on a given path and find valid paths but without valid credentials.

Comment: Hi, any update this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If the **access level** of your container is `Blob` or `Container`, just use the src like `src="https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/123.PNG"`.

If the **access level** is `Private`, you could not use the `src` above directly, otherwise, you will get a `404` error.

[image]

To fix the issue, you could generate a SAS token for the blob. Navigate to the azure portal -> find your image -> click `...` -> `Generate SAS` -> specific the parameter and click `Generate blob SAS token and URL`. The `Blob SAS URL` is the `src` you need, it should be like `src="https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/123.PNG?sp=r&st=2019-04-02T04:09:45Z&se=2019-04-02T12:09:45Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=xxxxxxZA0g%3D&sr=b"`.

[image]

[image]

**Result**:

[image]

For more details about **shared access signatures (SAS)**, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).